# How to redirect all non-www URLs to https://www. in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I want to add the proper 301 permanent redirect rule in IIS 8.5. I've added the following rules but it is not working.

```
 <rule name="Redirect top domains with non-www to www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*localhost.*" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*stage\..*" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*dev\..*" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:3}.{C:4}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

**Conditions**

- If the URL is in HTTPS and contains "www." then NO redirect. Example: https://www.example.com
- If the URL is in HTTP then it should be redirected to HTTPS. Example: http://www.example.com should be redirected to https://www.example.com
- If the URL is in HTTPS but does NOT contain "www." then it should be redirected to HTTPS site with "www." prefix. Example: https://example.com should be redirected to https://www.example.com
- If the URL neither contains HTTPS nor WWW then redirect to HTTPS URL with "www." prefix. Example: http://example.com should be redirected to https://www.example.com

To summarize, *every URL should be in HTTPS and should have "www." prefix*.

**NOTE:** I have installed [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in IIS.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed it by adding two URL rewrite rules in `Web.config` file:

1. For redirecting non-www to https://www.{domain}.com/...
2. Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS

   ```
   <rule name="Redirect top domains with non-www to www" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*localhost.*" negate="true" />
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*stage\..*" negate="true" />
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*dev\..*" negate="true" />
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
         <serverVariables>
           <set name="Redirect" value="false" />
         </serverVariables>
    </rule>


   <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*localhost.*" negate="true" />
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*stage\..*" negate="true" />
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*dev\..*" negate="true" />
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
   ```

All the conditions with `negate="true"` are used for exclusion. Hence all URLs which contains "localhost", "stage", and "dev" are excluded from URL rewrite. You can remove these conditions if not required.

Read more about **negate** attribute at http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Hi there, do you know how I can update the condition pattern (pattern="^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$") and the redirect url (http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}) so that they can capture & redirect domains such as .co.uk  & .uk.com ??

Comment: Hi, I copied your code verbatim, but when I enter `http://example.com`, it redirects to `https://example.com`...do you know why it's not redirecting to `https://www.example.com`?