# Redirect all URLs to HTTPS/WWW versions using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a website and just purchased an SSL. I want all URLs to redirect to their HTTPS/WWW versions. For example:

```
1. http://mywebsite.com       ->   https://www.mywebsite.com
2. https://mywebsite.com      ->   https://www.mywebsite.com
3. http://www.mywebsite.com   ->   https://www.mywebsite.com
4. https://www.mywebsite.com  ->   [No redirect needed]
```

I already tried some solutions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516613) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491202/1650088) from marked-as-answer approaches. But almost all of answers return "`Not Found. HTTP Error 404`" for case 2, i.e. `https://mywebsite.com` didn't redirect to `https://www.mywebsite.com` but returned 404 instead.

**Already-tried solutions:**

1.

```
<rule name="Redirect top domains with non-www to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="Redirect" value="false" />
      </serverVariables>
</rule>
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

2.

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.zzz.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

It seems some other people have this problem too. But I couldn't find the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `Site Bindings` section of IIS. There was no record for `https://mywebsite.com`. I added this record and the solutions in the question worked. For more info about this feature, visit [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh831681.aspx#Site_Bingings).